# Vuejs - On input, run a function (but with a delay)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I have an input field, and `v-on:input` it runs a method called `activate` that looks like this:

```
export default: {
    data() {
        return {
            isHidden: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        activate() {
            this.isHidden = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`isHidden` turns on/off some icon (it doesn't really matter what this data property is; I'm just using it for example purposes).

So currently, when a user does an `input` it immediately turns on the `activate` function. Is there a way to, perhaps, put it on a delay via `setTimeout`? I've tried doing the following but it doesn't work:

```
methods: {
    setTimeout(function() {
        activate() {
            this.isHidden = false;
        }
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: What type of input is it? With some inputs you may want to [debounce/throttle](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) any methods run when the `input` event is fired.

Comment: It's just a standard text input field. Joe Attardi's answer worked for me, but I will also look into debounce/throttle.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this:

```
methods: {
  activate() {
    setTimeout(() => this.isHidden = false, 500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Or without arrow function:

```
methods: {
    activate() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() { that.isHidden = false; }, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, without the arrow function you will lose the context of this.isHidden

Comment: @Besi that's why it's assigned to `that`.

Comment: @Kody and that's why arrow functions were created  for. The arrow function looks cleaner imo

Answer (score 1):

First, set a var in your data:

```
data() {
    return {
        typing: Date.now()
    }
}
```

then in your methods, create a function that will fire on keyup:

```
pendingSave(val){
    let saving = setTimeout(() => {
        this.saveItem(val) // method to call when user is done typing
    },1203)

    if(val){
        saving
        if(Date.now() - this.typing < 1200) clearTimeout(saving)
        this.typing = Date.now();
    }
}
```

In your HTML, you would have something like this:

```
<input v-model="title" v-on:keyup="pendingSave(title)" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
```

What happens is that when the user clicks inside the input, and types a character, it will call 'pendingSave()'. This will get the function ready to call via setTimeout() in 1203ms.  If the user types another character, and the time is 'less' than 1200ms, it will cancel setTimeout()... otherwise it will fire the function *saveItem()* as intended.